Regression in Google Sheets API - 502 Server Error
We have encountered a regression in the functionality involving the Google Sheets API. Our system is frequently receiving a 502 error with the following message:
That’s an error.
The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds. That’s all we know.

The issue affects multiple operations, including READ, WRITE, and DELETE actions across our system.
Could you please assist in identifying the root cause of this issue?

Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide minimal reproducible example

This is a known regression on Google side.
Issue tracking

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
